# UNION to merge tables has high cost, loses connection to server

Tags: postgresql, indexing, merge, union

I'm trying to create a new table as a `UNION` of all rows of two existing tables with identical columns:

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS
(SELECT * from table1
UNION
SELECT * from table2);
```

After running for a while, I get "Connection to the server has been lost."
Running `EXPLAIN`, the operation has quite high cost:

```
Unique  (cost=51951688.65..57110689.45 rows=257950040 width=36)
  ->  Sort  (cost=51951688.65..52596563.75 rows=257950040 width=36)
        Sort Key: table1.id, table1.stid, table1.e5, table1.e10, table1.diesel, table1.date, table1.changed
        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..8859500.00 rows=257950040 width=36)
              ->  Seq Scan on gas_prices  (cost=0.00..1282341.56 rows=66285256 width=36)
              ->  Seq Scan on gas_prices_1620  (cost=0.00..3707907.84 rows=191664784 width=36)
JIT:
  Functions: 1
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

So it's the sorting that's taking up a lot of resources.
I have set memory settings in postgresql.conf higher than default, but I'm only running on a system with 16gb of memory.
I suspect that re-indexing the existing tables could help, however I'm not sure which index to make. There is no private key on either table: No single or combination of column(s) is unique (except all columns at once).

How can I get the query to work? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UNION ALL instead of UNION.

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works! Ain't I likely to run into the same resource issue when I then go on to check for/delete duplicate records in the newly created table?

Comment: Well - you stated the rows were all different it must be a limited set of columns that count as duplicates and that's in your favour.  You'll need a whole lot of records to have ```group by ... having ...``` choke for example.